# Join Field based on multiple fields using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I am giving a simplified example, but the principle is the same for my problem. In the end I show you my actual case with a screenshot.

There are 100 municipalities. Their borders divide land data. Within each muncipality, there is 10 categories of land use, represented by 10 polygons that are multipart. So there are a total of 1000 polygons in the whole layer. The polygons have an ID-column with ID-numbers (1-100) representing each municipality, and they also have a land use column that show which kind of land use type each polygon is (1-10).

I also have table imported from Excel. It has one column with land use types 1-10 and one column with the same ID-numbers for each municipality (1-100). Is also has 10 columns for each land use type, which shows **kg of wood that can be found in each land use type**. That means that for each municiaplity, you can find different kg of wood, even though the land use type is the same.

My problem is that when I try to Join Field, I can only choose one column from the table to join the layer. I would like to also join the values of of kg of wood so that they match the land use type in each municipality. I am a newbie to ArcGIS Pro, and don't know to solve it.

Below a picture is added showing happened when I used Join Field without success (in my real case). To the right are six land use types that shows values in kg (phosphorus). The SUBID2016 is the ID-number column and the DETALJTYP column is the land use type column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as all your data sits within the same file geodatabase (so you will need to import your Excel file into it as a table) you can use the [Make Query Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-table.htm) tool to join on multiple fields. It's a very powerful tool but takes a little effort to play with the parameter settings and actually take the time to read the help file to understand what is what.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. This task seems rather daunting because I am on a short deadline. It seems I have to learn how to create an enterprise database to begin with. If https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-enterprise-geodatabase.htm

Is there no simpler way to do this? O.O'

Comment: @mentace - My mistake its the Make Query Table tool, I have updated my answer to link to the correct tool. No need to be using Enterprise Databases, can be done in a file geodatabase.

Answer (score -1):

A few years ago I had this problem. Searching on internet I found and for me it worked!!
https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/spatial-joins-hidden-trick-or-how-to-transfer-attribute-values-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/#comments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer on this site. Please at least summarize what's behind the link.